# Import files in objective-c using wildcard

Tags: objective-c, import, header, wildcard, glob

Is it possible to import a glob of header files based on wildcard directives? I want to semantically do the following:

```
#import "*-(Extensions).h"
```

to import all files in my local directory that end with `-(Extensions).h`. How might I go about this? Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope.

If you don't want to write a dozen `import` directives in multiple source files, you could write one header that imports all of your `-(Extensions).h` files, then import that into your source.

You could generate said header automatically from a directory listing with a bit of shell scripting, then make that shell script a build phase in your Xcode project.

Comment: yea.. but I already do that XD eventually somewhere you have to write every single one i see